# A suspended account and its days visited counter/records

Tags: discussion, questions

When an account is suspended, does the suspended account have the ability to keep their days "visited" or "consecutive" days visited streak alive, and increment the number up still during the suspension period?

*Does it make any difference whether a suspension is lifted early or goes out all the way through the period as originally intended?*

[image]

**Note:** *Knowing whether or not this is SU only or an all SE community standard could be helpful.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suspended users can still visit the site, and their visits are tracked like everyone else's. Their counters of days visited keep increasing, and they earn credit toward Enthusiast/Fanatic badges as well.

Source: own experience.

Note: there is nothing special about suspensions on SU compared to suspensions elsewhere on the SE network. It's the same thing everywhere.

Comment: Fair enough, if you experienced it then you experienced it so that's confirmation enough I suppose unless someone says otherwise. Appreciate the answer!